# How to change url variables with $location?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get code to work at jsfiddle which reads and changes the url variables in the url:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/3k4j4mz5/3

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope, $location, $log) {

    $scope.changeUrl = function() {
        var path = $location.path();
        var id =Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20;
        $location.url(path + '?customer=' + id);
        $log.info('path='+path);
        $log.info('id='+id);
    };

});
```

Why will the above code not add e.g. `?customer=23` at the end of the URL? Is the code not correct or is this a limitation of jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [$location Developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> $location service provides setter methods for url, path, search, hash

so you could change query string like this:

```
var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20;
$location.search({customer: id})
```

Comment: `$location.url()` will call `.search()` automatically.

Comment: thanks, that is an easier way to set the URL variables it seems and it works in my local example, but I'm trying to get it to work at jsfiddle, but it doesn't work there: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/3k4j4mz5/4/

Comment: jsfiddle is contained in an iframe, therefore it cannot change the parents location.

Answer (score 2):

Your example should work, but that is not possible in jsfiddle.  So, yes this is a limitation of jsfiddle.